# differential of the inverse function proof question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

If I have $g$ to be the inverse function of a continuous, strictly rising function $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is differentiable in $f'(y_0)\ne 0$, then g is differentiable in $x_0=f(y_0)$ with

$$g'(x_0)=\frac{1}{f'(y_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(g(x_0))}.$$

Proof:

There is a function $\varphi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous in $y_0$ s.t.

$$f(y)-f(y_0)=\varphi(y)\cdot(y-y_0)$$

and $\varphi(y_0)=f'(y_0)$. Because $f$ is strictly rising and $f'(y_0)\neq 0,\varphi(y)\neq 0$ for all $y\in I$, with $x=f(y),y=g(x)$ one gets

$$g(x)-g(x_0)=\frac{1}{\varphi(g(x))}\cdot(x-x_0).$$

Because $\frac{1}{\varphi\circ g}$ is continuous, $g$ is differentiable in $x_0$ with $\frac{1}{f'(y_0)}$.

My question is why is $\frac{1}{\varphi\circ g}$ continuous and how do we know that $\frac{1}{\varphi(y_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(y_0)}?$

Comment: I have a idea but it is basically just Intuition because $\frac{1}{x}$ is continious in $x =\varphi(y_0)\neq 0$ the composition must be also continious Right?

Comment: It is continuous because $\phi$ is everywhere continuous and $x^{-1}$ is continuous everywhere except 0. The composition of two continuous functions is continuous on the domain for which both are continuous and $\phi(y_0) \neq 0$ so $\frac{1}{\phi(y_0)}$ continuous on its whole domain. You know that the equality is true because $\phi(y_0) = f’(y_0)$...